# postgreSQL: Remove last character in a VARCHAR until match is found

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am looking for an efficient way to query a postgreSQL database by removing the the right-most character in a string until a match is found. For example, if my dialing number is `442079285200` then it should strip characters from the end of the sequence, eventually matching to UNITED KINGDOM-LONDON `44207`.

1. `442079285200` -> No match
2. `44207928520` -> No match
3. `4420792852` -> No match
4. `442079285` -> No match
5. `44207928` -> No match
6. `4420792` -> No match
7. `442079` -> No match
8. `44207` -> Matches UNITED KINGDOM-LONDON

**v_destination_rates**

| destination | dialing_code | current_rate | rounding_rule |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INMARSAT | 870 | 10.8239 | 1-1-1 |
| INTERNATIONAL NETWORKS | 882 | 10.8239 | 1-1-1 |
| INTERNATIONAL NETWORKS | 883 | 10.8239 | 1-1-1 |
| IRIDIUM | 521844207 | 5.1167 | 1-1-1 |
| UNITED KINGDOM-LONDON | 44207 | 0.0056 | 1-1-1 |

I know one way of doing this is to loop over the number of characters in the dialing number (n) and do a select query for the left-most n characters. I haven't successfully ran my query, but I believe it would look something similar to:

```
$do$
DECLARE
   m   varchar := '442079285200';
BEGIN
   FOR counter IN LENGTH(m)..1 loop
      select destination from v_destination_rates where v_destination_rates.dialing_code = left(dialing_number, counter);
   END LOOP;
END
$do$
```

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of performing this query, perhaps with the LIKE wildcard operator? We have thousands of dialing numbers to match to approximately 20 000 dialing_codes so a less expensive operation would be preferred.

Comment: you can try regular expressions and there are the big ones like elastic search if the the database is big

Comment: dialing code will always be in the left-most of the dialing number, so using regex should help.

Comment: You would use something like ```where dialing_number like dialing_code || '%'```.  This will give you the correct dialing code matching the start of dialing_number.  If there is a change of more than one match you might want to select the longest dialing code.

Comment: 0207 is not a dialing code, it is just 020 for Greater London. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UK_telephone_code_misconceptions Your table might work better if you split out the country code first as everyone has different ideas about how phone numbers are formatted.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said whether `dialing_number` is coming from a table / sanitized user input / something else.

For simplicity I'll assume it comes from a table `contacts` and that you want to return everything in `contacts` and every column in `v_destination_rates` joined as you describe.

Without using pl/pgSQL:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM contacts c
LEFT JOIN v_destination_rates vdr
  ON vdr.dialing_code::TEXT LIKE c.dialing_number::TEXT || '%'
```

I've tested this on a table of 9,000 records, which I assume is as about as large or larger than the lookup table `v_destination_rates`, and matched 16 sample integers in less than a tenth of a second.

You could possibly get even better performance if the dialing code is already type `TEXT`, and indexed lexicographically since that's how you're searching here.

Answer (score 0):

I generally avoid regular expressions and like/similar searches whenever possible; they are slow. In this case they are completely avoidable instead you can use `substring` and `length` and do a equal match. (yea, 2 subroutines vs regex it is a toss up). The following does just that and when multiple matches occur it selects the longest match. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3bfbb1cd182870f15f4d2c1f03cd1a2b))

```
with dialing_number (dn) as 
     ( values ('442079285200') ) 
select dr.* 
  from dialing_number
  join v_destination_rates dr
    on dr.dialing_code = substring(dn,1, length(dr.dialing_code)) 
 order by length(dr.dialing_code) desc
 limit 1 ;
```

Concerning performance, a search set of 20000 is a very small number of entries to search. For curiosity I generated random `dialing_code` values until the above query took more than 1sec. That occurred at 4755006 rows searched in 1.07 sec.

Comment: The benefit of this approach is you can make [an index on the expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) `substring(dialing_code, 1, 5)`. The problem is UK dialing codes are variable width so you'd need to either make many indexes, or pick a compromise one.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of performing this query

Yes, parse the number to get the country and dialing code. There are any number of existing libraries to do this. Then concatenate them and search.

For example, `442079285200` is the country code 44 and the dialing code 20 ([207 is obsolete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UK_telephone_code_misconceptions)). Then you'd search for '4420'.

Note: [870](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inmarsat), [882, and 883](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Networks_(country_code)) are not dialing codes, they are [*country codes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbering_plan). And [Iridium is 881](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Mobile_Satellite_System). Mixing up country codes with dialing codes will probably cause more problems down the road, you may be better off separating them in your table.